# Install dependencies in container using deps.edn

Tags: docker, clojure

I inherited a clojure code base and I'm trying to containerize it for local development. The creators used `deps.edn` to manage the dependencies. However, I can't figure out what `RUN` command I should use to pre-install the dependencies for the project.

Currently, my entrypoint is the following `['clj', '-m', 'app']` which installs the dependencies every time I start the container.

How do I pre-install dependencies for a clojure project using a Docker `RUN` command?

Answer (score 4):

Deps/CLI caching [is described here](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli#_classpath_caching).  Generally speaking, dependencies are downloaded once and saved in a subdirectory of the project directory named

```
./.cpcache  # "class path cache"
```

The `./.cpcache` directory is analagous to the `~/.m2` cache directory used by Maven and related tools (e.g. Leiningen).

If you run the code locally, you should be able to copy the `.cpcache` dir with its cached dependencies into your Docker container. Then the dependencies don't need to be re-downloaded
for each startup of the Docker container.

See also [the Deps/CLI overview](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli).

---

**P.S.**

[This template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) is set up to run using both `lein` and Deps/CLI via the Kaocha tool.  You may find the comparison helpful.

---

**P.P.S.**

You may find it easiest to run your code by building an uberjar file which contains all your code ***and*** all
dependencies in a single artifact.  You can do this either using Leiningen or other tools such as [depstar](https://github.com/seancorfield/depstar).  You then invoke the application with a single command like:

```sh
java -jar demo-0.1.0-standalone.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

Running this should do it:

```
clj -P
```